# Perform certain action for each 2 consecutive values from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I am currently working on a project that requires me to post data in a single form field to a script, which then does the following:

1. Since the posted data is in the format "value1:value2 value3:value4" and so on, explode it into an array and remove the empty spaces and the colons.
2. For each 2 consecutive values ( 0 and 1, 2 and 3, 4 and 5 etc. ), register those 2 values as 2 separate variables, and perform a certain action ( HTTP request to my server, which returns a TRUE or FALSE response after it compares the 2 values )
3. According to the response the server sent back, print a certain text for each of those pairs on the same page.

Here's what I got so far:

```
if(!empty($_POST['data']))  {
    $post = $_POST['data'];
    $array = explode(" ", $post);

    foreach($array as $k=>$v)   {

        $array[$k] = explode(':', $v);
        $username = $array[$k][0];
        $password = $array[$k][1];

        function IMAP($username, $password)  {

            $domain_hostname= '{imap.domain.net:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
            $domain_username= $username;
            $domain_password= $password;

            $imap_inbox = @imap_open($domain_hostname,$domain_username,$domain_password,0,1);

            if($imap_inbox == true)  {

                imap_close($imap_inbox);
                $valid = "1";
                echo $domain_username. "/" . $domain_password. " is a valid combination.\r\n";
            }
            else  {

                $error_array = imap_errors();
                $error = $error_array[0];
                $error_string = "[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.";
                $error_string2 = "LOGIN failed";

                if (strpos($error, $error_string) !== false) {
                    $valid = "0";
                    echo $domain_username. "/" . $domain_password. " is an invalid combination.\r\n";

                }

                if (strpos($error, $error_string2) !== false) {

                    $valid = "0";
                    echo $domain_username. "/" . $domain_password. " is an invalid combination.\r\n";
                }
            }
        }
        IMAP($username, $password);
    }
}
```

After I double-explode the posted string to remove both the empty spaces and the colons, I end up with arrays in the form of `$array[0][0]` and `$array[0][1]` for the first pair ( value1:value2 ), then $array[1][0] and $array[1][1] for the second pair ( value3:value4 ) and so on.

How do I make it so that for each 2 values a certain action is repeated over and over again, in the context of the same page, and then, depending upon the response, the appropriate text is printed for each pair?

Once I run the above code, and the POST contains 2 sets of username/password, only the first set is checked for by the IMAP server, and instead of the second one being validated, I get a fatal error saying:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare IMAP() (previously declared in )

Why is it stopping instead of doing the same for the second pair?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['data']))  {
    $post = $_POST['data'];
    $array = explode(" ", $post);

    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        $array[$k] = explode(':', $v);
        echo yourFunction($array[$k][0], $array[$k][1]);
    }
}
```

Just write a function that does whatever you want to do with that data, pass it both parameters when you explode them and print the function's output ?

Comment: I should have specified that the data I am posting contains multiple pairs of value1:value2 - not just 2 pairs.

Comment: I edited my original question - if I submit 2 sets of pairs, it only validates the first one successfully, and does not continue with the rest from the array - see my original question for details.

Answer (score 0):

You must not declare your function inside of the `foreach` loop -- php is being told to re-declare the same function on each iteration.

Simply declare the function at the start and call it as many times as you wish from inside the loop.

```
function IMAP($username, $password){
    $domain_hostname= '{imap.domain.net:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $domain_username= $username;
    $domain_password= $password;
    $imap_inbox = @imap_open($domain_hostname,$domain_username,$domain_password,0,1);

    if($imap_inbox == true){
        imap_close($imap_inbox);
        $valid = "1";
        echo $domain_username. "/" . $domain_password. " is a valid combination.\r\n";
    }else{
        $error_array = imap_errors();
        $error = $error_array[0];
        $error_string = "[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.";
        $error_string2 = "LOGIN failed";
        if(strpos($error, $error_string) !== false){
            $valid = "0";
            echo $domain_username. "/" . $domain_password. " is an invalid combination.\r\n";
        }
        if(strpos($error, $error_string2) !== false){
            $valid = "0";
            echo $domain_username. "/" . $domain_password. " is an invalid combination.\r\n";
        }
    }
}
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $post = $_POST['data'];
    $array = explode(" ", $post);
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        $array[$k] = explode(':',$v);
        $username = $array[$k][0];
        $password = $array[$k][1];
        IMAP($username, $password);
    }
}
```

This will eliminate your error.